Is there a way for stage NOT to execute in Gitlab manual pipeline unless variable is specified
Given the Gitlab CI Stage below, i want it to run on any changes to terraform/* or config.json or if there is variable defined, either via git push -o ci.variable=... or by defining it in Manual pipeline.
However, when i run manual pipeline (without any variables definedd), all stages including the one defined below is executed (that one is also the first one, all others come after it).
I thought the -when: never would handle it but it doesn't appear so.
Is there any way to make it work
Deploy EC2 Instance:
  rules:
    - changes:
      - terraform/*
      - config.json
    - if: $CI_TERRAFORM_APPLY == "yes"
    - when: never
  tags:
    - docker
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: deploy_instance
  before_script:
    - echo "Preparing environment ..."
    - apk add curl jq python3
    - python3 -m venv .venv
    - ./.venv/bin/pip3 install boto3 requests
    - ./.venv/bin/python3 ./scripts/configure.py
    - python3 scripts/load-env.py > .env
    - . .env
  script:
    - |
      if [ -z $CI_SKIP_BACKUP ]; then
        echo "Checking if there are any wars to backup for re-deployment ..."
        if nc -zv $CFG_elastic_ip 22 > /dev/null 2>&1 && nc -zv $CFG_elastic_ip 9990 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
          ./.venv/bin/python3 ./scripts/extract-wars.py
        fi

        echo "Extracting system properties ..."
        if nc -zv $CFG_elastic_ip 22 > /dev/null 2>&1 && nc -zv $CFG_elastic_ip 9990 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
          ./.venv/bin/python3 ./scripts/extract-system-properties.py > system-properties.json
        fi

        echo "Extracting datasources ..."
        if nc -zv $CFG_elastic_ip 22 > /dev/null 2>&1 && nc -zv $CFG_elastic_ip 9990 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
          ./.venv/bin/python3 ./scripts/extract-datasources.py > datasources.json
        fi
      fi

    - |
      echo "Running terraform tasks ..."
      cd terraform
      terraform fmt
      terraform init -input=false
      terraform validate

      if [ -z ${CI_TERRAFORM_DESTROY} ]; then
        terraform plan -compact-warnings -input=false -out plan.cache
      else
        terraform plan -destroy -compact-warnings -input=false -out plan.cache
      fi
      
      terraform show -json plan.cache | jq -r '( [.resource_changes[]?.change.actions?] | flatten) | { "create":(map(select(.=="create")) | length), "update":(map(select(.=="update")) | length), "delete":(map(select(.=="delete")) | length) }' > plan.json

      if [ -z ${CI_TERRAFORM_DESTROY} ]; then
        terraform apply -compact-warnings -input=false plan.cache
      else
        terraform apply -destroy -compact-warnings -input=false plan.cache
      fi
    - |
      cd ..
      tar -zcf store.tar.gz .env *.war *.jar datasources.json || true
  artifacts:
    access: 'developer'
    paths:
      - terraform/plan.cache
      - store.tar.gz
    reports:
      terraform: terraform/plan.json

